# Is it correct to say "You be the best"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage, inflectional-morphology, african-american-vernacular-english

This phrase is in constant use by many lately , just to appreciate a person in something.

But I personally feel there's some problem in this - "*You are the best*" makes better sense.

Is this even grammatically correct to use it? OR is there any alternative?

Comment: It has a dialectical usage - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be

Answer (score 4):

If it's a command, then it's correct. For example a coach could say to a player, if you want to win, you be the best!

Comment: Although not forbidden, imperatives of the second person seldom include an explicit subject. Exceptions would be things like “You tell ’em, Rocky!” and “Go thou and do likewise.”

Answer (score 0):

If it is, indeed, used "just to appreciate a person in something," then I would venture to say that depending on whose mouth it emanates from, that it would be a form of mocking someone else's dialectical pattern for "you are the best". A poor attempt at humor with resultant racist undertones. Not nice.